# ¿Por que da error al agregar fila en Mysql?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, webservice

Tengo una aplicación android conectada por webservice a una base de datos en Mysql, cuando agrego filas a una tabla ya creada llego hasta la numero 12 y desde ahí no me deja agregar mas, ya que cuando abro la aplicación para ver esos datos, no aparecen, he probado con el navegador y sucede lo mismo.

Mi archivo php es este

```
<?php

  $host = 'localhost';
  $bd = 'tecnomas_addonskd';
  $user=$_REQUEST['user'];
  $pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
  $conex = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tecnomas_addonskd","$user","$pass");
  $res = $conex->query("SELECT * FROM `addon_spanish` WHERE 1");
  $datos = array();
  foreach ( $res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row;
  }
 echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

La linea que trato de agregar es la siguiente

```
(13, 'Vodmx', 'Peliculas – series – infantil – deportes – anime', 'Repo desde la fuente - addons video', 'http://repo.vodmx.tv/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/bDKQml2nHo.jpg')
```

No se si sea por la linea o por que me falta configurar algo, la estructura de la base de datos es

[image: Estructura base de datos]

Agrego captura de operaciones de la tabla

[image: operaciones de la tabla]

**2da Edicion**

Estoy insertando los datos desde el mismo phpMyAdmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la fila 13 si la lee, estuve revisando y creo que era un inconveniente con tildes, la cambie pero después de la 14 sucede lo mismo.

Sin agregar la fila con id 14

[image: Sin agregar la fila 14]

Agregando la fila con id 14

[image: Agregando fila 14]

La llave primaria es el id, al exportar la tabla para ver todo en código me sale el siguiente archivo .sql, creo que puede ayudar para resolver el por que no lee algunas filas

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `addon_spanish`
--

CREATE TABLE `addon_spanish` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `instalation` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `patch` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dislikes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `logo` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `addon_spanish`
--

INSERT INTO `addon_spanish` (`id`, `name`, `content`, `instalation`, `patch`, `user`, `likes`, `dislikes`, `logo`) VALUES
(1, 'Compus1286', 'Live Tv - Peliculas - Series', 'Fuente - Video Addons - Addon', 'http://compus1286.com/compus1286_repo/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/FPY4xiaTs8.png'),
(2, 'Bassfox', 'Peliculas - Tv en vivo - Musica - Radio - Salud - Fitness', 'Repo Bassfox desde la fuente - Addons de video', 'https://tecnomasterlh.com/addons/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/f08TRiF-_p.png'),
(3, 'Movies PR', 'Peliculas - Series', 'Repo INTRCOMP MEDIA - Addons de video', 'http://intrcomp.net/intrcomp/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/et_azpLoL6.png'),
(4, 'Avezy', 'Deportes', 'Fuente - Addons deportivos - Addons', 'http://catoal.org/', 'Agustin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/eSVJIh-OkU.png'),
(5, 'Insomnia', 'Anime - Peliculas -Series - Noticias - Musica', 'Fuente - Plugins', 'http://canalnereo.com/canalnereo/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/GG9XoMFvUj.png'),
(6, 'Colombia Tv', 'Tv online (solamente canales de colombia)', 'Addon desde la fuente', 'https://tecnomasterlh.com/addons/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/3oYAqBlets.png'),
(7, 'Americano Tuga', 'IPTV - Tv 24/7 - Movies 1080p - Tv Shows', 'Repo vipsecrettv - Addons de video', 'http://vipsecret.amerikanotuga.tech/VipSecrettv/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/iUsnXq0OwF.png'),
(8, 'Exabyte Tv Privado', 'IPTV (requiere registro en su web oficial)', 'Addons desde la fuente', 'http://exabytetv.info/repo/', 'Danzig28', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/JiKAPPnfoJ.png'),
(9, 'Palantir', 'Peliculas - Series - Secciones infantiles', 'Fuente - plugins', 'http://canalnereo.com/canalnereo/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/9bBSKnN006.jpg'),
(10, 'Zerov', 'Peliculas - Series - Anime - Musica - Tv', 'Repository desde la fuente - addons de video', 'https://www.free.zerovblack.com/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/GpdqXhF_Wp.jpg'),
(11, 'Mundo Infantil', 'Peliculas - Series infantiles', 'Repository Colussus - addons de video', 'http://mybuild.darkwebrepo.gq/install/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/HKz3aq1Cff.jpg'),
(12, 'JHG Master', 'Contenido completo (video)', 'Fuente - Repos - JHG Repo - Addons de video', 'https://tecnomasterlh.com/addons/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/IhV2NHqPeg.jpg'),
(13, 'Vodmx', 'Peliculas ', 'Repo desde la fuente - addons video', 'http://repo.vodmx.tv/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/bDKQml2nHo.jpg'),
(19, 'Planeta', 'Documentales - Video animales - Videos Naturaleza', 'Fuente - plugins', 'http://canalnereo.com/canalnereo/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/v_1vNf_DnF.jpg');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `addon_spanish`
--
ALTER TABLE `addon_spanish`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: podrias poner una captura de lso datos de la tabla?

Comment: @PaolaCasianosipac edite la pregunta y agregue la captura que creo me pides colocar

Comment: Realiza lo siguiente y me dices:
-Verifica que la conexión se realice sin problemas.
-Si tu campo id es auto incrementable, al momento de hacer la inserción no lo envies.
-si tienes algun mensaje de error, por favor anexalo a la pregunta.
-prueba hacer la inserción directamente por sql.

Comment: Hola, dices que da error, pero no reportaste el error, el que no liste los datos no es un error, pues no existen en la base de datos,  el php que nos muestras parece ser solo la consulta y el problema según entiendo es al insertar, comparte el php que hace el insert, ahi debería estar el problema.

Comment: ¿El `13` correspondería a la columna `id`?  ¿Dicha columna es llave primaria y auto_incremental?  Si es así deberías poner `NULL` en vez del `13` o mejor aún omitir esa columna del `INSERT`.  Quien sabe si ya existe un registro con `id=13`. De todos modos, le faltan datos a tu pregunta. En vez de imágenes comparte mejor el código que usas para insertar y el mensaje de error que estás teniendo.

Comment: Edite la pregunta agregando mas datos que pueden ayudar @A.Cedano la llave primaria si es el id, pero en la tabla apenas están los elementos mostrados, por lo tanto no hay alguna repetida.

Comment: que quiere decir que no lee? en que sentido no lee? si haces un select *...

Comment: @gbianchi me refiero a las dos ultimas imágenes que agregue, en una lee el JSON en la segunda no

Comment: y la consola de debug dice algo? hay algun error?

Comment: @gbianchi la consola no muestra ningún error

Comment: por favor, agrega echo por todos lados, para ver hasta donde llega o que esta pasando...

Comment: Creo que el error lo esta dando al momento de crear el `$datos = array();` ya que al agregar las lineas `(14, 'Pandora', 'Peliculas – series – television', 'Addon desde la fuente', 'https://tecnomasterlh.com/addons/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/3ORxXVyZOx.jpg')` y `(21, 'Tv chopo', 'Peliculas – series – infantil – deportes - hogas - gym', 'Fuente - Repos - Tv Chopo - Addons de video', 'http://canalnereo.com/canalnereo/', 'Admin', 0, 0, 'https://cldup.com/N9v7KIite0.png')` creo que hay algún carácter que hace romper el foreach